# how to rewrite HTTP get request with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need `.htaccess` rule to reroute:

`example.com/view-post.php?id=40` to `example.com/article/40`

So browser shows `example.com/article/40` in address bar but server uses `example.com/view-post.php?id=40`

Comment: What is not understandable? Provide us with Your code, errors.

Comment: Hi there. It looks like [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025203/why-not-working-two-post-route-in-laravel) you received the answer you needed, and then deleted the question. While you are allowed to delete your posts, it is not in the spirit of Stack Overflow to delete a question if useful answers will be deleted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)*$ ./view-post.php?id=$1
```

Refer: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Comment: What URLs are you trying for CSS and JS?

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess won't work in nginx server. So you should try the following code to route using php script only. Keep this script in your index.php file.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(preg_match('/article/', $url)){ 
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/view-post.php?id='.$id;  
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
  echo $httpResponse;
}else{
  echo "404 Error, Page not found";
}
```

If you have another route url Ex. example.com/post/40 and example.com/porfile/40 then you could add a condition in if as below,

```
if(preg_match('/article/', $url) || preg_match('/porfile/', $url) || preg_match('/post/', $url)){
```

I hope this answer will help you :)

Comment: The question says .htaccess