# htaccess rule for pretty URLs

Tags: .htaccess

I have a web site working on localhost for now. 
I send some data with get method to another controller
When I send data my url is look like:

http://localhost/book/Control/?kolon=&satir=unknown&modals=infox&bookid=4555

but i want to it look just like:

http://localhost/book/4555

I tried editing my .htaccess file like below but it does not work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Control/?kolon=&satir=unknown&modals=infox&bookid=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to rewrite HTTP get request with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057125/how-to-rewrite-http-get-request-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the pretty URLs through htaccess.

The following is tested and works works:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^book/(\d+)*$ ./book/Control/?kolon=&satir=unknown&modals=infox&bookid=$1
```

Refer: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it in that way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^book/(.*)$ Control/?kolon=&satir=unknown&modals=infox&bookid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

If bookid it's a numeric value you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^book/([0-9]+)$ Control/?kolon=&satir=unknown&modals=infox&bookid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: no, it is not working again, is it become because of that ı run it in my localhost ?

Comment: Try removing RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f and RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d